# Puzzling function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Let $f$ be a function whose domain is the set of positive integers, and for positive integers $a$, $b$ and $n$, if $a + b = 2^{n}$, then $f(a) + f(b) = n^2$. What is $f(2021)$?

I started by testing values for $a$, $b$ and $n$, with the hope of finding a pattern, but so far I can't say I've made any headway;

For $a=b=n=1,\ f(1)+f(1)=2^1, so f(1)=\frac{1^2}{2}=\frac12$

I realize that it becomes easier to find $f(a)$ if $a$=$b$

So $a = b = 2^{n-1}$  then $f(a) = \frac{n^2}{2}$
that is, $f(2^{n-1}) = \frac{n^2}{2}$

At this point, I cannot see where to move forward.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural starting point might be to find $f(k)$ for small values of $k$.

Comment: Note:  may be worth remarking that $f(k)$ doesn't seem to be an integer for some small $k$.  Nothing wrong with that, I suppose, but is it what you intended?

Comment: please include you efforts

Comment: In your $a=b=n=1$ example, I think you mean: $1+1=2 = 2^1$, so $f(1) + f(1) = 1^2 = 1$ and thus $f(1) = 0.5$.

Comment: Note that $2021+27=2048=2^{11}$ thus you can obtain $f(2021)$ in terms of $f(27)$. Repeat the process till you get a known value

Comment: @Aufklärung FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(a)%2Bf(b)%3Dn%5E2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a%2Bb%3D2%5En%24&p=1), I found the AoPS thread [Intrduction to Algebra 16.22](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h568513p3334394). Although it asks to find $f(2002)$ instead, the approach used there will work for your case as well, as also already explained in the [comment](/questions/4479674/puzzling-function#comment9392492_4479674) above, and the [answer](/a/4479708) below.

Comment: Is it obvious that the function $f$ exists?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A nearby power of $2$ to $2021$ is $2048=2^{11}$. So you know that $f(2021)+f(27)=11^2$ since $2021+27=2048$.
Great, but now we need to know $f(27).$ Well, a nearby power of $2$ to $27$ is $32=2^5.$ So then because $27+5=32$, we know that $f(27)+f(5)=5^2$.
Continue in this way until you get down to some small powers of $2$, which you can directly compute.
Hope this helps.

Comment: $2021+27=2048$, but $2021+37=2058$.

Comment: Yikes, excuse me. Editing appropriately now.

Comment: If possible, could you list out that continuation?

Comment: Sorry, just seeing this request now. We would next need to find $f(5)$. For this, note that $5+3=8=2^3$, so $f(5)+f(3)=3^2=9$. Now we need $f(3)$, so we use $3+1=2^2$, so $f(3)+f(1)=2^2=4$. A comment by rogerl points out that $f(1)=.5$. Now you can back solve all the way up to $f(2021)$.